# Is it possible to create operator kubernetes for a kind that already exists? eg kind namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I need to monitor the creation of new namespaces in my k8s infrastructure so that when new namespaces are created a series of commands should be executed like assigning permissions and pvc creation, could someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. But showing how to do it is way out of scope for a StackOverflow answer. The short answer is you do it just like any other controller but the root object is something from Kubernetes core rather than your own struct(s).

Comment: Coderanger, thank you very much for your answer, how to get this information on google I spent the day looking and I didn't find anything respect, any information helps.